# Heroku handling Tanker 'tankit' differently than locally with regards to Messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, heroku, indexing, message

I am using the rails gem Tanker in order to use Searchify in my app. I am also using acts-as-messageable in order to allow users to send messages. In my acts-as-messageable model I have

```
      tankit 'idx' do 
             indexes :topic
             indexes :body

             indexes :sender_name do
                sent_messageable.name
              end
              indexes :sender_username do
                sent_messageable.username
              end
       end
```

Locally this runs fine. However on Heorku when I run `rake tanker:reindex` I get the following error: `Indexing Message model
rake aborted!
undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

I assume this is because it is not recognizing sent_messageable as a User. (Acts-as-Messageable does not REQUIRE this to be a User, I just us it as one). Is there a way to cast it to User?

In java I would do (User)sent_messageable, however this also raises an error (syntax this time).

Thanks.